# Insertar datos de un id especifico de la bbdd con php

Tags: mysql

Hola buenas noches espero que alguien pueda ayudarme:

Quiero mostrar con php los datos de una fila o id especifico, de una tabla llamada "lagrimita" que esta en una bbdd llamada valentin_articulos, quiero traer todos los datos de ese id en un arreglo y luego en el html mostrarlos pero no en forma de tabla, van separados en distintos p y uno de ellos es la ruta de una imagen.

Este es el php, pero importo toda la tabla yo solo quiero traer una fila con el id= 10 x ej.
Muchas gracias desde ya

```
<?php
    $servername = "server";
    $username = "valentin_admin";
    $database = "valentin_articulos";
    $password = "contra";
    $sql = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database;";
    $dsn_Options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];

    // Crea una nueva conexion con mysql,
    try { 
       $my_Db_Connection = new PDO($sql, $username, $password, $dsn_Options);
          echo "Connected successfully";
       } catch (PDOException $error) {
          echo 'Connection error: ' . $error->getMessage();
    }
    //conecta con bbdd
    $base=mysql_select_db('valentin_articulos',$sql),
    if(!$base) {
         echo "no conecto bd: " . mysql_error();
    }else {
         //conecta con la tabla
         $datos = "SELECT * FROM LAGRIMITA";
         $ejecutar_sentencia=mysql_query($datos);
         if (!$ejecutar_sentencia){
              echo "hay un error en la sentencia de sql" . $datos;
         }else {
         //carga el arreglo
              $lista_art=mysql_fetch_array($ejecutar_sentencia);
           } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tienes que ponerle un filtro a la consulta para que te traiga solamente los del id que quieres, algo así: **`$datos = "SELECT * FROM LAGRIMITA WHERE id=10";`** asumiendo que la columna se llama realmente `id`, si no fuera así, basta con poner el nombre correcto de la columna.

Answer (score 0):

Para traer los datos filtrados como indicas es necesario usar un filtro `WHERE` en la consulta.

Pero hay más errores en tu código, como la mezcla de mysqli y de PDO (que son dos APIs distintas y no deben mezclarse).

Propongo una solución basada en PDO. Aplicando también una práctica correcta para el `fetch`. Tienes que recuperar los datos dentro de un bucle, porque los métodos como `fetch` de PDO `fetch_array` de mysqli, ponen el puntero en la primera fila del resultados, si no sigues moviendo el puntero no obtienes los otros datos (por eso el bucle `while`).

Este es el código. He puesto varios comentarios. Si hay algo que no entiendes me lo dices.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

```
<?php 
    $servername = "server";
    $username = "valentin_admin";
    $database = "valentin_articulos";
    $password = "contra";
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database;";
    $dsn_Options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];

    // Crea una nueva conexion con mysql,
    try { 
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $dsn_Options);
            echo "Connected successfully";
    } catch (PDOException $error) {
            echo 'Connection error: ' . $error->getMessage();
    }
         # Array para guardar resultado del código según éxito o error 
         $arrResult=array();
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM LAGRIMITA WHERE id=10";
         $stmt=$pdo->query($sql);
         if (!$stmt){
              # Si hay error el array tendrá una clave error dentro
              $arrResult["error"]= "hay un error en la sentencia de sql:".$stmt->errorInfo()[0];
         }else {
              $lista_art=array();
              while ( $row=$tmt->fecth(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                  # El array se llenará con cada valor
                  $arrResult[]=$row;
              }
         } 
        # Prueba del array 
        print_r($arrResult);
        /* 
            Si el dato se recibe en otra parte, 
            se puede hacer algo como esto:

            if( isset($arrDatos["error"]) ) {
                echo $arrDatos["error"];
            } else {
                #Trabajar con el array de datos exitosos
            }
        */     
?>
```